# C++ binary predicate version of std::all_of()?

Tags: c++

Given two `std::vector<T>`s, `vec_a` and `vec_b`, does the standard library include a function to test if every element in `vec_a` is less than its positionally corresponding element in `vec_b`, assuming the binary `operator<` is defined for operands of type `T`?

I would think something like a binary predicate version of [`std::all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) would do the trick perfectly, but I'm not sure if it exists, or what it would be called if it did.  Perhaps also some combination of `std::all_of` applied to the output of another function which performs elementwise comparison would work, if such a thing exists.

---

Example of desired functionality:

```
std::vector<int> vec_a{1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> vec_b{2, 3, 4};

bool all_less = vec_a.size() == vec_b.size();
for (size_t i = 0; all_less && (i < vec_a.size()); ++i) {
    all_less = vec_a[i] < vec_b[i];
}

// all_less now holds desired result
```

Comment: Have you tried `bool all_less = vec_a.size() == vec_b.size() && vec_a < vec_b`?

Comment: `std::vector` has an [operator <](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp).

Comment: @Zereges that performs lexicographic comparison, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes it does, and if you'll read the doc you linked you'll see it doesn't do what I've asked for.

Comment: Maybe [`std::mismatch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) can be used.

Comment: Ahah! Yep, though a little convoluted logically.  Unfortunately I think it may end up being harder to read than the vanilla method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::mismatch`, although it's a bit harder to comprehend (but is a one liner, yay)

```
std::vector<int> vec_a{1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> vec_b{2, 3, 4};

bool all_less = std::mismatch(vec_a.begin(), vec_a.end(), vec_b.begin(), vec_b.end(), std::less<>{}) == std::make_pair(vec_a.end(), vec_b.end());
```

You can help it a bit by introducing a function for containers and not ranges. I.e

```
template<typename Container>
bool is_all_less(const Container& c1, const Container& c2)
{
    return std::mismatch(c1.begin(), c2.end(), c1.begin(), c2.end(), std::less<>{}) == std::make_pair(c1.end(), c2.end());
}
```

and then

```
bool all_less = is_all_less(vec_a, vec_b);
```

#### Edit

If you are sure that containers are of the same `size`, you can also do this

```
bool all_less = std::mismatch(vec_a.begin(), vec_a.end(), vec_b.begin(), std::less<>{}).first == vec_a.end();
```

Comment: I'm not sure 145 characters qualifies as a one liner under any reasonable code style, haha.  (But you did find the standard library function to answer my question!)

Comment: @Apollys Yeah, I came up with slightly shorter version.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`std::equal`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal):

```cpp
bool all_less = std::equal(vec_a.begin(), vec_a.end(),
                           vec_b.begin(), vec_b.end(),
                           std::less<>());
```

The `vec_b.end()` argument can be omitted if the vectors are already known to have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think that an approach like `std::equal`+`std::less` is more idiomatic, because you're essentially asking if all pairs of corresponding elements are "equal" with a custom equality predicate.

Besides, the approach of `mismatch` inherently comes with the necessity of processing the containers in sequence, whereas in principle `std::equal` could be parallelized.

Now, I know you asked for a solution of the standard library, but Range-v3 builds on top of that indeed, and here's how terse a solution with Range-v3 can be:

```cpp
// assuming these
#include <range/v3/algorithm/equal.hpp>
#include <range/v3/functional/comparisons.hpp>
using namespace ranges;

// a short oneliner
bool result = equal(vec_a, vec_b, less{});
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++23 there's a generalisation to an n-ary predicate:

```
std::ranges::all_of(std::ranges::views::zip_transform(std::less<>{}, vec_a, vec_b), std::identity{});
```